# Can I rely on a Navmesh for X/Z movement and manually place my agent on the Y axis?

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, navmesh

I'm generating my terrain mesh around the player (along with collision mesh and Navmesh). It's tile based, when the player moved enough I generate necessary tiles render meshes, then collision meshes and then I generate a whole new navmesh surface data (in the background) to swap with the current one. The setup is a sand desert with no obstacles and no slope too steep to climb, basically you can go everywhere.

Computing render and collision mesh is rather fast, but navmesh takes about 30s. I could not tweak values to make it faster without noticeable quality loss. I'm trying to find a workaround before going too deep this way (I might add simple obstacle later).
I tried using one navmesh surface per tile (instead of a single global one) but then I have to link them and that seem complicated and very noticeable.

**I'm wondering if I could juste generate a navmesh according to an hidden plane underneath my terrain, and then simply reposition the agents along the world Y axis each frame ?** Are there obvious issues that will arise or should that be fine ?

Comment: "The setup is a sand desert with no obstacles and no slope too steep to climb, basically you can go everywhere" Why do you need a navmesh at all in such a situation? Wouldn't it be easier to not generate a navmesh at all and not use NavMeshAgents, but rather just move your characters with your own movement script? If the obstacles you plan to add later are "simple" then you may be able to get around them with local avoidance, rather than navmesh pathfinding.

Comment: I guess you're right, its probably easier to script it. I wanted to learn about Navmesh generation, it seemed more robust to me in the long run. I'm still curious about my question though: is it more complex than it look to handle navmesh in 2D and manually adjust the last dimension in a 3D game ?

Comment: I just think you lose many of the benefits of the navmesh, using it this way. Navmeshes are great for simplifying your runtime pathfinding cost via pre-computation. If you're generating them at runtime, you lose some of that edge. They're great for long-distance pathfinding — but if you're chopping up into cells, you lose a lot of that benefit too. They're great for simplifying navigation of complex terrain with obstacles, but if you have no obstacles and you're handling the verticality of the terrain separately, you miss out there too. So they're not doing any of what they're good at here.

Comment: Well that's a lot of good points. Thanks for all the explanations !

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing pathfinding in two dimensions if that is all you need. But as @DMGregory pointed out it might be the wrong use case here.